# Merging two csv files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am having problems getting my csv file to format correctly when merging it with another. I have the following code:

```
list_dir = glob.glob('C:/.../*')
imprint = 'C:/.../imprint_report.csv'
export_dir = 'C:/.../Export//'

for imprint_d in csv.DictReader(open(imprint)):
    for list_file in list_dir:
        list_token = os.path.basename(list_file)[:6]
        if imprint_d['token'] == list_token:
            v = open(list_file, 'rb')
            r = csv.reader(v, delimiter='\t')
            row0 = r.next()
            row0.append('token')
            all_rows = []
            for item in r:
                item.append(imprint_d['token'])
                all_rows.append(item)
                #print item
            output = open(export_dir+list_token+'_append.csv', 'wb')
            writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator=',')
            writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

Which successfully merges the data I need, however the formatting is incorrect. Rather than have the appended data be set to each row and maintaining the format of `list_file`, where `x` is the data I am appending:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
  a       b       c       x
  d       e       f       x
  g       h       i       x
```

I get all data being merged into one row like so:

```
a    b    c    x    d    e    f    x    g    h    i    x
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Change `lineterminator=','` maybe?

Comment: @fp That did it, changed `lineterminator=','` to `lineterminator='\n'` and now I'm good. Make that into an answer so I can accept it and close this question out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `lineterminator=','` maybe?